# Swift - Read Google Sheets

Tags: swift, google-sheets

I'm working on an app that uses Google Sheets as a database, but I can't figure out how to get Swift to read from google sheets.  I've looked through the API website and a few questions on here but I need some help just getting started. So far I have;
    private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets]
    private let service = GTLRSheetsService()

```
    var range = "Form Responses 1!A1:D3"
    let spreadsheetId = "p;;;;;;p;;;;;;;;1LqXa6v75JE8RQQDOI4Z_g8mUT8x0DhsEDwRIaxDN-DU" // Portfolio
    let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet.query(withSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range:range)
    service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
```

Which I got from another question on here...
But 'displayResultWithTicket' is an unresolved identifier. Currently it gets to the last line, and debugging I'm not even sure what to do with the 'query' value. I'm really not even sure if it's reading the correct spreadsheet. How can I tell?

Long story short, I'm lost.

Comment: Take a look on this documentation, this might help: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/ios

Answer (score 1):

I recently made an app that uses Google Sheets. But I used the CSV file for the database. This might help. If you want, I can share the details.

Comment: That would be absolutely brilliant if you would!

Comment: Yes! That would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to export the Google Sheets file in CSV format. I used [Realm](https://realm.io/) to read CSV. Using [Realm Studio](https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/), you need to create the columns as in the CSV file. Then you can import the CSV file into Realm Studio. Your database is ready.

In **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** to find the file created after installing Realm on your project

```
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!.path)
```

Now we will use the database with Swift. 
For this, we must first add the Realm file that we prepared to the XCode project directory. Then we use it in ViewController this way to get data.

```
var realm : Realm!
```

For get the data in default.realm file

```
    let realmPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "realm")!
    let realmConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: realmPath, readOnly: true)

    do{
        realm = try Realm(configuration: realmConfiguration)
    }
    catch {
        print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

You can export the result to an array. I hope it helps.

Comment: Do you export Google Sheets to CSV in your app? I have the Google Sheet updating with information constantly.

Comment: You can import the data from Google Sheets in JSON format. Then you can follow this method. You want to dynamic CSV file. But I don't know if this is possible. For example you can get JSON in AppDelegate.